# cannot locate LinearMath/btMatrix3x3.h

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I intend to convert quaternion into rpy using btMatrix3x3.getRPY(). However, i get the following error when i try to compile.

this is done with only `#include <LinearMath/btMatrix3x3.h>` included in my cpp file.
/home/chao/catkin_ws/src/simple_navigation_goals/src/robot_state3_with_class.cpp:23:36: fatal error: LinearMath/btMatrix3x3.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

this error msg showed up when i added `<depend package="LinearMath"/>` into the `manifest.xml`

```
[rospack] Error: package/stack 'simple_navigation_goals' depends on non-existent package 'LinearMath' and rosdep claims that it is not a system dependency. Check the ROS_PACKAGE_PATH or try calling 'rosdep update'
```

appreciate your help, thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/132241/cannot-locate-linearmath/btmatrix3x3.h/) by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on ROS Answers with karma: 153 on 2014-02-23

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You don't mention which ROS distribution you are using, but if it is Groovy or Hydro, you want to include

```
<tf/LinearMath/btMatrix3x3.h>
```

and depend on tf, not LinearMath, which is not a package.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-02-23**:
my apologies for the negligence. yes, i am using Groovy with Ubuntu 12.04. I suppose that the  you mentioned is to be included in my cpp file? like this (  #include   ) ?

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-02-23**:
I have tried to put #include <tf/LinearMath/btMatrix3x3.h>, #include <tf/Matrix3x3.h> but it shows error

**Comment by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) on 2014-02-23**:
apparently ROS answers mucked up my answer, those should be slashes... see the edit above

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-02-23**:
Hi, i have tried to put #include <tf/LinearMath/btMatrix3x3.h> but it shows ##fatal error: tf/LinearMath/btMatrix3x3.h: No such file or directory## My tf package is at /opt/ros/groovy/share/tf and inside has ##cmake  msg  package.xml  srv## Could it be possibly that there is something wrong with my tf package?

**Comment by [chao](https://answers.ros.org/users/9591/chao/) on 2014-02-28**:
Hi, i managed to find the answer already :) it is in the package bullet. just put "#include<bullet/LinearMath/btMatrix3x3.h>" will do. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For anyone coming here looking for the kinetic version (like me), it is `#include <tf/LinearMath/Matrix3x3.h`

---

Originally posted by [ufr3c_tjc](https://answers.ros.org/users/28584/ufr3c_tjc/) with karma: 885 on 2017-06-07

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For Melodic users (like me) it is `"tf/LinearMath/Matrix3x3.h"`. Make sure to include `<build_depend>tf</build_depend>` in your `package.xml` and add `tf` to `find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS)` in your `CmakeList.txt`

---

Originally posted by [raghavthakar](https://answers.ros.org/users/51049/raghavthakar/) with karma: 11 on 2021-05-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Glumerlink](https://answers.ros.org/users/87730/glumerlink/) on 2021-10-21**:
This was the exact thing i was missing thanks, i didn't realize i was making use of the tf2 library